# Is it necessary for a new user to visit meta.SO first before posting in meta.movies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I guess meta.SO is the oldest site among other meta sites of stack exchange. So several typical questions like queries on Community Wiki, User Community, How to be unbanned, Who is diamond moderator, who is moderators etc. have been discussed already in meta.SO. So when a new user joins in Movies.SE, he can also have these typical questions in his mind. Naturally he would post the questions in meta.movies. But they have been already discussed in meta.SO. So in these cases, the answers would contain the links to meta.SO. So I think in the FAQ section, it should be written as suggestion that first try searching answers to questions like these(there will be examples given) in meta.SO, if not found, then return and post to this site. Or another thing can be done that we link the search result of this site with the search result of meta.SO, so that the questions that are already been discussed, a new user can view them directly searching from here and they even need not to open a new account in meta.SO. Now we only can search within meta.movies and see the result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that meta.stackoverflow.com does provide many answers to how the stackexchange system as a whole works.... reputation, voting, badges etc.  Many times on this meta, the answer often links to an answer on meta.so

I think that adding something to the FAQ here would be useful to direct people to meta.so for additional support - there are perhaps some people on this site that are not even aware of stackoverflow.

The suggested search feature providing results from both this site and meta.so is potentially confusing as meta.so does also deal with the meta issues of a programming site - it has that dual purpose.  There has been some discussion about breaking meta.so up so that the aspects that relates to how all stackexchange sites work is separate from that relating to just stackoverflow. Until that happens, I think a search which could return results relating to programming questions might be a little surprising to people.

Comment: So make some changes in FAQ to suggest people to go through meta.SO first!

Comment: I will do so (later)  :-)